# Como guardar datos que vienen desde una tabla en un array

Tags: javascript, php, html

En el `tbodyDS`, Una vez pintados los datos. Estos son los que deseo guardar en un `array` como muestro a continuación...

```
$(document).on("change",".sistemaN",function(event){ 
var sistema=$(".sistema").val(); 
var sistemaN = $(this).val(); 
var hallazgoSistema=$(".hallazgoSistema").val(); 
if(sistema!="" && hallazgoSistema!="" && sistemaN!=""){ 
    $("#tbodyDS").append(<tr>      <td>+sistema+</td>      <td>+hallazgoSistema+</td>      <td>+sistemaN+</td>      </tr>); 
} 
$(".sistema").val(""); 
$(".hallazgoSistema").val(""); 
$(".sistemaN").val(""); });

let datos = []; document.querySelectorAll('.tabla-datos tbody tr').forEach(function(e) { 
let fila = { 
Sistema: e.querySelector('.sistema').innerText, 
Hallazgo: e.querySelector('.hallazgoSistema').innerText, 
Gravedad: e.querySelector('.sistemaN').innerText 
}; 
datos.push(fila); 
}); 
console.log(datos);
```

[image: como lograr guardar estos datos en un array]

Comment: $(document).on("change",".sistemaN",function(event){

     var sistema=$(".sistema").val();
     var sistemaN = $(this).val();
     var hallazgoSistema=$(".hallazgoSistema").val();


     if(sistema!="" && hallazgoSistema!="" && sistemaN!=""){

     $("#tbodyDS").append(`<tr>
     <td>`+sistema+`</td>
     <td>`+hallazgoSistema+`</td>
     <td>`+sistemaN+`</td>
     </tr>`);

     
     }

     $(".sistema").val("");
     $(".hallazgoSistema").val("");
     $(".sistemaN").val("");
});

Comment: let datos = [];

     document.querySelectorAll('.tabla-datos tbody tr').forEach(function(e) {

     let fila = {

     Sistema: e.querySelector('.sistema').innerText,
     Hallazgo: e.querySelector('.hallazgoSistema').innerText,
     Gravedad: e.querySelector('.sistemaN').innerText

     };
     datos.push(fila);

     });
     console.log(datos);

Comment: El codigo lo escribir arriba .. en tu pregunta, tampoco mencionas claramente cual es el problema, que pretendes lograr y de que forma has intentado realizarlo.

Comment: Quiero guardar los datos que estoy pintando en la tabla en un array

Comment: Ahora debemos saber como lo has intentado, que error arroja o cual es el comportamiento inesperado de tu función

Comment: Intente con un foreach, el inconveniente que tengo es cuando intento agregar mas datos a la tabla, en el array me aparecen duplicados.

Comment: Trata de poner en la pregunta únicamente la parte del código donde tienes problemas, no se trata de poner un programa completo, quizá por eso dice que es demasiado código. Luego, el planteamiento es confuso. ¿Estás leyendo un array de alguna parte y queriendo mostrarlo en una tabla o al revés? ¿Revisaste la estructura y contenido de ese array para ver si no es que los datos en sí mismos vienen duplicados? Parecería que depurando adecuadamente darías con el problema y si no, plantéalo de la forma más clara posible para que podamos ayudarte mejor, sin desesperarte ni ahogarte en un vaso de agua,

Comment: si amigo, el problema es que no puedo guardar los datos del tbodyDS en un array...

Comment: Pues pon el HTML del `tbodyDS` y el código con el que intentas recoger el contenido de ese elemento (ambos contenidos en texto, no en capturas de imagen), y si es posible, un `console.log` de lo que estás recogiendo por código. Como te dije antes, limita el código de la pregunta al problema concreto, donde éste ocurre, indicándonos lo que has depurado y con qué resultados.

Comment: De todos modos, en el código se aprecia lo contrario de lo que dices querer en tu anterior comentario, pues esto: `$("#tbodyDS").append(` lo que haría sería **agregar más contenido a `tbodyDS`** no recoger contenido de él para guardarlo en un array.

Comment: Asi es amigo, con el $("#tbodyDS").append( es agregar mas contenido a la tabla... Lo que deseo es tomar todo ese contenido de la tabla y almacenarlo en un array

Comment: Como te vengo diciendo, clarifica tu problema, pulsando en [edit], porque ni siquiera se entiende qué es lo que quieres hacer. Si quieres tomar datos que ya existen en `tbodyDS` no tiene sentido usar `append` (que es para añadir contenido, no para recoger contenido). Para recoger contenido puedes usar por ejemplo `querySelectorAll`  y luego, según la estructura de la tabla, sacar los datos que te interesen. Si no explicas eso con claridad, mostrando el HTML de `tbodyDS` lamentablemente no podremos ayudarte a encontrar una solución a este problema.

Comment: El appen lo uso para mostrarlos en la tabla. y cada vez que agrege a mi tabla es tomar los datos y guardar en el array